# TypeError: Int object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am trying to generate dataset for OCR using different fonts, but upon a certain for loop, the iteration giving me and error `Typeerror: int object is not iterable.`
I have searched enough to conclude that most of the answers on StackOverFlow suggests to use the range in my for loop including (len) but I am not sure if I follow that.

The function is as follows:

```
def gen_rand_string_data(data_count,
                     min_char_count=3,
                     max_char_count=8,
                     max_char=16,
                     x_pos='side',
                     img_size=(32, 256, 1),
                     font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                     font_scale=np.arange(0.7, 1, 0.1),
                     thickness=range(1, 3, 1)):
'''
random string data generation
'''
start_time = dt.datetime.now()
images = []
labels = []
color = (255, 255, 255)
count = 0
char_list = list(string.ascii_letters) \
            + list(string.digits) \
            + list(' ')
while (1):

    for fs in font_scale:
        for thick in thickness:
            for f in font:
                img = np.zeros(img_size, np.uint8)
                char_count = np.random.randint(min_char_count, \
                                               (max_char_count + 1))
                rand_str = ''.join(np.random.choice(char_list, \
                                                    char_count))
                # generate image data
                text_size = cv2.getTextSize(rand_str, f, fs, thick)[0]
                if x_pos == 'side':
                    org_x = 0
                else:
                    org_x = (img_size[1] - text_size[0]) // 2
                org_y = (img_size[0] + text_size[1]) // 2
                cv2.putText(img, rand_str, (org_x, org_y), f, fs, \
                            color, thick, cv2.LINE_AA)

                label = list(rand_str) + [' '] \
                        * (max_char - len(rand_str))
                for i, t in enumerate(label):
                    label[i] = char_list.index(t)

                label = np.uint8(label)
                images.append(img)
                labels.append(label)
                count += 1
                if count == data_count:
                    break
            else:
                continue
            break
        else:
            continue
        break
    else:
        continue
    break
end_time = dt.datetime.now()
print("time taken to generate data", end_time - start_time)
return images, labels
```

The error raised is at line : `for f in font:`

What am I doing wrong here? Do I have to use the range()?

Comment: Did you try it with `range`?

Comment: post the complete error

Comment: Yes at the `error` line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
for f in font:
    ...
```

In CV2, the font is a simple integer representing the font itself, I'm not *entirely* sure<sup>(a)</sup> why you're trying to iterate over it.

If you wanted to iterate over *sizes* of the font, you would have to use (for example) the `fontScale` parameter of `putText()`.

If you want to iterate over a *collection* of fonts, you have to provide that collection, such as with one of:

```
font = [cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX]                         # one font as a collection
font = [cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN] # two fonts
```

If you only have the *one* font, then don't iterate over it at all. Get rid of the `for f in font` line (unindenting the stuff currently "inside" it) and just use `font` wherever you're currently using `f`.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Python is having *similar* troubles trying to figure out your intent :-)